# Picture does't show in the django admin page

Tags: python, django

Hey guys so i have a field in my database that contains the url to a picture.
So when i check a user, or when i wan't to modify one i get : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJxhT.png)

So the question is : how can i show the image instead of the whole  thing .

My code : 
models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    prenom = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/media')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    def image_tag(self):
        return u'<img src="/media/%s" />' % self.photo
        #return mark_safe('<img src="/static/%s" width="150" height="150" />' % (self.image))

        image_tag.short_description = 'Image'
        image_tag.allow_tags = True
```

admin.py :

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id','nom','prenom','age','photo']


    fields = ( 'nom','prenom','age','image_tag' )
    readonly_fields = ('image_tag', )
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`format_html`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) in order not to escape HTML characters.

```
from django.utils.html import format_html


def image_tag(self):
    return format_html(u'<img src="{}" />', self.photo.url)

image_tag.short_description = 'Image'
image_tag.allow_tags = True
```